# Is it possible to have a black hole in empty space?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, mass, orbital-motion

If the escape velocity of two very massive objects is **near** the speed of light, and those objects are orbiting each other (let's ignore the Roche limit for this exercise), is it possible that the combined mass of these two objects is great enough that their **center of mass**, while in the empty space between, is effectively a black hole? Is it possible that this is already the case with black holes we've observed, but we're unable to tell, due to the information capturing nature of black holes?

### Update

The reason I asked this question is that the the [recent discovery of a very massive black hole](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2015/02/26/389250817/astronomers-discover-a-supermassive-black-hole-dating-to-cosmic-dawn) made me wonder whether it was possible that this black hole was in fact a collection of **nearly** coalesced stars (perhaps from many galaxies), and its combined mass was so great that, while locally there was information due to its accumulation of space time, it appeared to our quiet part of space as one large black hole. I didn't initially mention this because I didn't want to distract from the fundamental idea on which my question was predicated.

Comment: How would you define a black hole?

Comment: Mass so great that light cannot escape.

Comment: If you define it like that it is trivial that, at a point where there is no mass, there cannot be a black hole. You have to be more careful in the definition. My point is that this may well just be a matter of definition rather than something very interesting physically

Comment: Isn't a center of mass meaningful? After all, isn't that what a black hole is comprised of, non-contiguous particles with a center of mass?

Comment: The center of mass between two objects is just a concept, it has no physical properties...

Comment: What makes a black hole gain physical properties? It's not just one thing, but rather a concept derived from the center of mass of its constituent particles, no?

Comment: But it is each particle that is providing the physical properties, we simply group them to make it easier than calculating every single particle on its own.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing though? Where does the continuum end and the matter of fact begin in this theory? Take, for instance, a black hole that had a large gap between two ends of its mass, and that gap was held apart by metal bars (unobtainium bars :). Would that no longer be a black hole, even though its center of mass was between the two?

Comment: Think about it in terms of force. There would still be an average force caused by all the particles which would not allow for light to escape. Grouping the particles is convenient because as you get farther away a point mass becomes a better and better model. So yes if you are asking strictly if light could not escape the general vicinity, sure, possibly.

Comment: One thing that may be important to mention here is that a black hole is *completely* specified by its total mass $M$, its angular momentum $J$, and its charge $Q$. This is the "no-hair theorem", and it shows that things like strange mass distributions etc cannot happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Even if the two bodies could be compressed to be just larger than their Schwarzschild radius (they can't really, without collapsing further to black holes), their combined Schwarzschild radius, which grows linearly with mass, is twice their individual Schwarzschild radii. That means that even if they effectively rolled on each other surfaces, they would still, by construction, be just larger than the combined Schwarzschild radius. If you wanted to compress them the go below, then you would need to compress the individual bodies to go below their individual Schwarzschild radii.

Also, anything that forms a black hole will collapse to a point, keeping no memory of its former constituents (like the number of objects used to create it). Only mass, charge, and angular momentum is remembered.

Comment: This answer then concludes that no object can be dense enough to be a black hole unless all of its constituent parts are "touching", which would then conclude that anything inside of a Schwarzschild limit has to be bonded (quite perfectly bonded). Is this true?

Comment: Okay, I'm not a general relativist, but I can't think of any setup where that could happen. BHs are formed from collapsing stars, whose constituents "touch". But as I added in my answer, even if it somehow were possible, the non-touching constituents would collapse to a point. If they carry angular momentum, which in general they do, it will actually not be a point, but a [ring-shaped singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_singularity), but still well within the Schwarzschild radius.

Comment: Is there some special principle that causes them to just suddenly "collapse to a point" after not having done so prior to containing the exact amount of mass necessary, or is it just reaching the proper point on the continuum, and it's simply paradoxical to think of objects as being able to exist in this situation without having already collapsed (presumably incrementally, due to the Roche limit)?

Comment: I guess the thing I'm having a hard time with is accepting that, while mass is energy, that it's somehow not possible to have some combination of mass **and** kinetic energy (in the form of angular momentum) which equals the same mass required to form a black hole. It feels like magic to think of a scenario where these principles don't apply.

Comment: Yes, you could say that there is a special principle. It's when pressure "gives in" to gravity. Gravity will always try to pull a star into a black hole. For a normal star, this pull is counteracted by radiation pressure from the energy production on the core. When the star has exhausted its fuel, it collapses to a compact object, either a white dwarf (supported by electron degeneracy pressure), or a neutron star (supported by neutron degeneracy pressure), or a black hole, depending on the initial mass. Adding mass continuously to a neutron star would cause it to suddenly collapse at 2-3 Msun.

Comment: What I'm asking is different. The scenario I'm describing is two orbiting bodies whose (to reference your example) combined mass is 2-3 Msun, but whose individual mass is not enough for each body to collapse into its own black hole. (thanks for all the replies and help - I'm really trying to understand this)

Comment: Okay, I didn't consider other forms of energy than pure mass. I think that mass-energy will always be much larger than angular momentum energy, since c is such a large number (in E=mc²).

Comment: Ah, so then it comes down to the nature of my scenario, where the objects in question would have to orbit at a velocity near the speed of light to maintain this scenario (assuming the escape velocity of their combined mass is near the speed of light). Is this possible, if matter were continuing to be added to the two bodies in a manner which didn't interrupt their angular momentum, but in a manner which caused their orbits to downgrade and thus accelerate? Is the structural integrity of the objects (due to the energy limitations of bonds) the only prohibiting factor in a scenario like this?

Comment: The larger the angular momentum, the larger the mass needed in order to create a collapse, so a rapidly spinning neutron star can be more massive. However, the upper limit for a neutron star (the "Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff limit") is still [~3 Msun](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.3995v3.pdf), I think. The Schwarzschild radius of such an object is ~9 km. Concerning your last question, I will let someone more knowledgeable answer, before I get myself in trouble. Also, SE asks me to move this discussion to chat. Also, I need to leave now. :)

Comment: No problem, thanks for taking all the time to talk through this with me. It's been very helpful.

Comment: You're very welcome :)